# I have programmitacally added TextViews in my app, need help in setting id for each TextView

Tags: java, android

I need to set Ids programmatically for my TextViews, so that i can use their text and set their text from another activity.

This is the function which adds a TextView on Button press-

```
public void addNote(final View view)
{
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    TextView tt = new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.setMargins(15,15,15,15);
    tt.setLayoutParams(p);
    tt.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BorderGray));
    tt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tt.setId(numberOfLines + 1);
    tt.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.shape));
    tt.setPadding(50,50,50,50);
    ll.addView(tt);
    numberOfLines++;
    tt.setHint("What do you want to remember?");

}
```

I am also  not sure how setId works in there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `setID` you can use the `setTag` method. So,

```
tt.setTag("note" + numberOfLines);
```

and then for retrieving the element use

```
TextView tt = (TextView) findViewByTag("note" + number);
```

The number variable for example can be a position in a list or numberOfLines.